# Can you check my proof of this equality?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

#### Prove that

$$\lVert x-y\rVert^2+\lVert x+y \rVert^2 = 2 \lVert x \rVert^2+2 \lVert y \rVert^2 \\ \text{for all } x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$$

##### My proof:

I will manipulate right-hand side of equation to make it equal to the LHS by adding and subtracting $2 \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert $:
$$2 \lVert x \rVert^2+2 \lVert y \rVert^2 $$
$$2 \lVert x \rVert^2+2 \lVert y \rVert^2  + 2 \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert  - 2 \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert ​$$
$$ \lVert x \rVert^2+  2 \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert + \lVert y \rVert^2  ​+  \lVert x \rVert^2 - 2 \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert +\lVert 
y\rVert^2 $$
$$ \lVert x+y \rVert ^2 + \lVert x-y \rVert ^2$$
Thus, RHS is equal to LHS.

##### The problem

It says that equality should hold for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p $. I am certain that this proof is correct for $p=1$ and $p=2$, but in higher dimensions I just don't know. Can anyone highlight the weak side of the proof and give an advice on how to make it more solid.

##### (The edit:)

Ok, thanks for all in the comments, now I understand my mistakes.
First of all, I should have mentioned that $ x,y \in \mathcal{V} $, where $\mathcal{V}$ is the inner product space, and the norm we are dealing with is induced in this inner product space $ \mathcal{V} $. Since, for any $ u \in \mathcal{V}, \lVert u \rVert = \sqrt{<u,u>}$ , we can proceed with following calculations:

LHS:
$$ \lVert x-y\rVert^2+\lVert x+y \rVert^2  = <x-y, x-y> + <x+y,x+y> $$

RHS:
$$ 2 \lVert x \rVert^2+2 \lVert y \rVert^2 = 2<x,x> + 2<y,y> $$

We can prove equality very easily by extending inner product brackets in LHS by linearity and symmetry properties, but we will do what I wanted to do initially ( we add and subtract $2<x,y>$):

$$<x,x> + <x,y> +<y,y> +<x,y> + <x,x> - <x,y> + <y,y> - <x,y>$$
$$ <x,x+y> + <x+y,y> + <x,x-y> - <x-y,y> $$
$$ <x+y,x+y> + <x-y,x-y>$$

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, the cross term when expanding $\|x+y\|^2$ is $2 \langle x, y \rangle$, not $2 \|x\|\|y\|$. Once you make this correction in your proof, I think your work will be correct.

Comment: This is the parallelogram law, so it only works when the norm is induced by an inner product (which you don't even mention in your proof), so your proof is incorrect. I suggest you recall the definition of the norm induced by an inner product, namely $\|\xi\|^2=\langle\xi,\xi\rangle$.

Comment: On top of the two previous comments, there is also something wrong between line 2 and line 3 where an additional term appears.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you I will correct it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, sorry for the mistake and thanks for noticing